# How to control the file dates in git?

Tags: git, file, time

See this repository, https://github.com/steeve/france.code-civil/tree/master/Livre%20III/Titre%20VII
there are files of 48 years ago... How to do it?

Can I preserve old dates after commit? No conflicts in git when changing dates?

PS: the aim in this example is to simulate document time and to reproduce  the sequence of changes in the real world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the `--date` argument to `git commit`. For example:

```
git commit --date="Wed Feb 16 14:00 2037 +0100"
```

You can edit an existing date, too: use `git commit --amend`.

For more information, check out [Working with dates in git](https://alexpeattie.com/blog/working-with-dates-in-git).

Comment: Note that this is good for dates as far back as 1970, the start of the Unix epoch. Git can't record dates prior to that.